# Checking if a person is in the correct posture using openCV?

Tags: opencv, android-camera

I was playing around with openCV on Android and was wondering how I can implement this feature.

Let's say we have 2 images. One is the ideal image, and the other is an image of the user of this application. I want the user to turn on their camera and stand in a certain way. I will use the application to tell them if they're standing properly.

For example, let's say I want the user to raise their hands. Once the user raises their hands, then I will verify that they are indeed raising their hands. My application relies on the app verifying that the person is in the correct posture, I cannot use user input.

I've considered histogram matching an ideal image and the real image, but it wouldn't work if there are different colors in the image.

I feel that one possible method could be to use edge detection to detect the user and have an edge detected image of the ideal. Then I would compare the two images. I just don't know how exactly to compare them? Maybe overlap them and see if there's no difference?

I understand that different body shapes would require a different ideal image, but let's say that we're talking about an average male.

Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe take some research on skeletal body pose estimation, like it is used in kinect. Not sure if this is possible in 2d. I know there is a paper, using 3d body templates with a chamfer matching to 2d image.

Comment: @Micka it is possible in 2D up to certain degree... like in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.01583.pdf) or [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf)... but probably is to heavy for an android device (they rely on deep learning) and also he may not be able to do it with OpenCV. Maybe another machine learning approach may give you the 2D skeleton, but i think this is no trivial problem

Answer (score 0):

Doing this would be extremely difficult in my opinion. I've been doing research in computer vision for a while and I haven't encountered something like this. Usually it can be done with a 3D model, such as with Xbox Kinect, but otherwise it is not a trivial task and will require a lot of unique research.

There isn't much out there about this subject so it is very difficult to do, especially if you are still a beginner with CV.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its possible using opencv. There are libraries in opencv that deals with image processing. However, i was never able to do image comparison with it in my project that deals with kinnect. And if you are planning on doing it manually, that will be to the another level.